# Scroll events unintentionally changing Material UI slider values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a React application that is utilizing Material UI. The application has slider components implemented in a lot of places (https://material.io/components/sliders). When using a touch screen device, I am unintentionally impacting slider components (the value is getting changed) while trying to scroll up or down the page. This does not happen with other page components, I suspect this is because sliders do (and should) respond to swipe events.

Material UI has documentation that implies a way to discern between a "scroll" and a "swipe" (https://material.io/design/interaction/gestures.html#types-of-gestures). Is there a way for me to indicate to my slider components that a "scroll" should be ignored. Or, can I discern between a vertical or horizontal swipe, telling the slider to ignore vertical swipes?

Comment: I have the same question!

Comment: Supply code example of your current usage for more help.

Comment: Does the Material UI page you linked to on sliders have the same undesired effect of changing the slider values as you scroll up and down on your mobile device? If not, then it is something with your implementation which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a fairly elegant solution, I believe, which allows the user to scroll if their scroll position begins on the track but not on the thumbs. This replicates the native HTML range input so I feel that this is the best solution.

There's two parts to this

Step 1, allow `touch-action` on the slider root element as it is disabled by default and prevents the user from starting a scroll on the slider

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  sliderRoot: {
    touchAction: "auto"
  }
});

return (
  <Slider
    classes={{
      root: classes.sliderRoot
    }}
    ...
  />
```

Step 2, stop propagation on the root element with a `ref`

```
const ref = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current) {
    ref.current.addEventListener(
      "touchstart",
      (e) => {
        const isThumb = e.target?.dataset.index;

        if (!isThumb) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      },
      { capture: true }
    );
  }
});

return (
  <Slider
    ref={ref}
    ...
  />
```

And here is a fully working demo on Codesandbox.

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: pretty neat solution, could you add some more sliders to your codesandbox to better showcase the scenario

Comment: When I try your example on CodeSandbox I can put my finger right on the slider thumb, scroll down and the slider moves. You're back to telling your users to watch out where they put their fingers.

Comment: It should be fine because that is how the native HTML range input works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Answer (score 0):

There is not going to be a completely clean solution to this other than telling your users to watch their finger placement when scrolling on mobile devices.

Using a controlled Slider, one approach would be to listen to the `touchstart` event and record the current `pageY` on the first `changedTouches` object. Then compare that coordinate to the `pageY` on the `onChangeCommited` event handler for the corresponding `touchmove` event. If the difference between the two coordinates is larger than some predefined range, then do not update the Slider `value`.

Inside your component using the `Slider`:

```js
  const delta = 50
  const sliderRef = useRef(null)
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0) // Or from some prop
  const [touchStart, setTouchStart] = useState(0)
  const debouncedHandler = useMemo(() => {
    // Using lodash.debounce
    return debounce((evt, value) => {
      // If it is a mouse event then just update value as usual
      if (evt instanceof MouseEvent) {
        setValue(value)
      }
    }, 25)
  }, [])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (sliderRef.current) {
      sliderRef.current.addEventListener('touchstart', evt => {
        setTouchStart(evt.changedTouches[0].pageY)
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Slider
      value={value}
      ref={sliderRef}
      onChange={debouncedHandler}
      onChangeCommitted={(evt, value) => {
        if (evt instanceof TouchEvent) {
          if (Math.abs(touchStart - evt.changedTouches[0].pageY) < delta) {
            setValue(value)
          }
        } else {
          setValue(value)
        }
      }}
    />
  )
```

This will prevent the Slider from changing `value` on `TouchEvent` when the difference between the starting y-coordinate and the ending y-coordinate is larger than `delta`. Adjust `delta` to whatever value you like. The tradeoff is that you will not get as smooth of a transition when adjusting the Slider with a normal `MouseEvent` (or `TouchEvent` within the predefined range).

See the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/morganney/jnsvyfgt/61/).

Or `npm i mui-scrollable-slider-hook` and use it like

```js
  import Slider from '@mui/material/Slider'
  import { useMuiScrollableSlider } from 'mui-scrollable-slider-hook'

  const { ref, value, onChange, onChangeCommitted } = useMuiScrollableSlider()

  return <Slider ref={ref} value={value} onChange={onChange} onChangeCommitted={onChangeCommitted} />
```

An example of using `mui-scrollable-slider-hook` on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-hill-e9ikq).